# Reactive form Email Validation Issue with gmail (+) addresses in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7

While testing with plus sign with a combination of words in my email address, i see that the plus sign is being removed. Has anyone encountered this problem ??

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems like a problem with the network request you're sending. It's most likely a GET and it's also most likely not URLEncoded. `+` is a space in a URL.

Comment: @VLAZ the request method is post. Thank you.